# Periodic lost of selected gnome-shell theme in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell

In Ubuntu 18.04, I noticed that my gnome-shell theme would periodically revert to the default theme and I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and key in <kbd>r</kbd> +  <kbd>Return</kbd> to refresh the gnome-shell theme so that the selected theme (in Tweaks) would appear again.

**Question**: May I know what is causing this periodic lost of the selected gnome-shell theme and how to avoid this periodic loss?

**Update1:** Per @Vanadium comment, I am using the [McHigh Sierra GTK3 Theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013714/). I will explore trying another theme to see if this issue is specific to this theme.

**Update2:**
The issue has also occurred when a totally different theme "Flat-Remix-fullPanel Panel" was used.

Comment: Possibly an issue with the theme itself, so mention the theme in your question and test whether it happens with different themes as well

Comment: @vanadium I have included a link in my question to the theme that is in use on the system.

Comment: Good. Also report back by editing your question if the issue returns with another theme or not. That helps confining the possible causes of the problem.

Comment: @vanadium it seems to also occur on another theme.